# Joint Probability Given

Tags: probability

I've seen this question floating around:

The joint probability of events A and B is `32 percent` with the probability of event A being `60 percent` and the probability of event B being `50 percent`. Based on this information, the conditional probability of event A given event B has occurred is closest to:

The answer is 32%/50% = 64%.

My question, where does the stated 32% joint probability come from?

If joint prob of A and B is P(AB), shouldn't the problem say?

```
The joint probability of events A and B is `30 percent`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If events A and B were known to be independent of each other, you could calculate the joint probability with $.6 \times .5 = .3$. But since the problem doesn't assume that they're independent, then the joint probability could be anywhere from 10% (smallest possible overlap) to 50% (event B always occurs with event A).

Comment: Just to be sure, the overlap is simple math: Minimum (.6 - .5) and Maximum(.6, .5)?

Comment: Minimum = (.6 - .5) * and Maximum = Minimum(.6,.5)*

Comment: To get the minimum, .6 + .5 - 1, because the total probability can't be greater than 1 in real life, so if .6 + .5 adds up to something >1, we know that extra 0.1 has to be due to overlap. You're exactly right about the maximum.